# Color distinction between native and custom classes

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

In Visual Studio, is there any chance I can make a color distinction between Microsoft .net native objects and methods (like Object, WriteLine etc.) and objects - classes and methods - defined by myself?

What I'd like to achieve is ie:
`System.Object` to be highlighted as usual, but
`MyClass.DoSomething()` to be highlighted in different color.

Comment: @leppie: Why remove the visual-studio-2010 tag? This is a question about syntax coloring in Visual Studio.

Comment: i dont think out of the box. what defines the line between built-in and custom? is a 3rd party library built in or custom? is another class library in the same built-in or custom?

Comment: i did put back general visual studio tag

Comment: `Microsoft C# native objects (like Object, WriteLine etc.)` `WriteLine` isn't native to C#.  It's just a method in the .NET library.  There are *very* few types actually baked into C#.

Comment: ok, yes, I should write native to .net. I corrected my question

Comment: There's really no distinction. These classes have moved between assemblies in the past. There's nothing special about them.

Comment: make them color distinctive, you can easily get know what group of objects is native and which group is yours. Thinking forward, if you can make even this color distinctions between your classes it could help you to read your code faster. Does somebody know where is the best place to make a suggestion to M$?